# C# Read Sharepoint List - Without Automagic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I need to complete a very simple application.  We want to archive some Sharepoint Lists at work to a SQL Server so that another application can run some analysis on them.  However every tutorial I can find gives the Automagic "First connect by right clicking the references and selecting "Add web reference"...

I can't use that method because the dev environment cannot see the production system (and we dont' have a test system, sorry).

I need to connect completely programmatically, open a list, and export it directly to a table (though the export is less important, it's the connection I'm missing).

So I need to connect to a list ala "SiteURL/_vti_bin/"

Comment: Can you run your application on the SharePoint server?  If so, you could use the SharePoint object model instead of the web service located in _vti_bin.  It would be a LOT faster and you would only need the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll to do your coding.

Comment: Yeah, we can't run directly on the server.  We're a small department and it's a corporate server for our company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't run the application on the server using the object model.  You can always create your "automagic" web reference by hitting a publicly facing `Lists.asmx` web service on the internet and just changing your url at runtime.

Comment: Great idea.  Do you happen to know of one?

Comment: Just google "Lists.asmx reference" and you'll find one pretty quickly.